# Get asp:CheckBox ID in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How do I retrieve the asp CheckBox ID that is in gridview inside the same gridview? Right now, it is saying the name is not in the current context

Comment: you mean to say gridview inside a gridview in that you need to find checkbox, can you share your code?

Comment: you kindly share your code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve in the `RowDataBound` event

```
       protected void gvFirstGridView(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                GridView gvSecondGridView = e.Row.FindControl("2ndGV") as GridView;
                CheckBox c = (CheckBox)gvSecondGridView.FindControl("2ndGVCheckbox);
            }
       }
```

else on `Button` Click

```
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvFirstGridView.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                GridView gvChild = (GridView)row.FindControl("2ndGV");
                if (gvChild != null)
                {
                    foreach (GridViewRow childRow in gvChild.Rows)
                    {
                        if (childRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                        {
                            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)childRow.FindControl("2ndGVCheckbox");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```